# Easiest way to convert images to mp4 with FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I will try to explain my situation : I know that FFMPEG is the best tool to work with PHP to have transcode operations. I'm in a Windows environnement and I have PHP 7.

**What I need is : with a php file, to take all pictures in the folder (1.png; 2.png) etc and then process with FFMPEG to create a MP4 video**

I know there is a lot of documentation on the Web about PHP, FFMPEG, PHP-FFMPEG but I don't know the easiest way to implement what I want. I also know that PHP needs FFMPEG binaries to work (which is logical). But I'm lost in the procedure and the way to do it.

Is it possible with the exec function ?

```
exec("PATH IN THE PROJECT OF EXE -f image2 -i /home/phedra/imgs/image/img%03d.png -r 12 -s 610x489 /home/phedra/imgs/video/out.avi", $out);
```

Do I absolutely need PHP-FFMPEG ?

Comment: Start here: [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP). You don't need a wrapper or library such as php-ffmpeg or ffmpeg-php to do this.

Comment: So, the "shell_exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi output.avi &");" with the right command  in parenthesis to should work ?